# VBA Loop through indeterminate blocks of text

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a schedule of shifts organized into monthly schedules for employees for an entire year. Each employees schedule for the month is separated by two blank lines, and each month is separated by 10. I am trying to format a calendar style schedule next to each schedule.

I have it set up such that when it finds the start of a new schedule, it loops through the current region and puts each shift into the calendar next to it. However, I only need it to loop through the schedule once, and then I want it to "step" to the next schedule in the sheet. Any way to find the next region in the for loop?

I will attach a picture of how it looks.

[image: excel Sheet image]

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub BuildMonthLines()

Dim wkb As Workbook, shift_lines As Worksheet, month_lines As Worksheet, inputs As Worksheet
Dim d As Integer, w As Integer, last_row As Double, shift_line As Double, shifts As Double


Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("Call Center Headcount Model v8.xlsm")

Set shift_lines = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Shift Lines")
Set month_lines = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Month Lines")
Set inputs = wkb.Worksheets("Inputs")

last_row = month_lines.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

shift_line = 3

For shift_line = 3 To last_row
    If month_lines.Cells(shift_line, 1).Value <> "" Then
        For shifts = shift_line To Cells(shift_line, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + shift_line
            With month_lines
                .Cells(shift_line + .Cells(shifts, 9).Value, 12 + .Cells(shifts, 8).Value) = month_lines.Cells(shifts, 7).Value
            End With
        Next shifts
    End If
Next shift_line
               
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcomee to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] then improve question! E.g. **never** show data as image! **Always** show data as text [formated as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) as we want to copy and paste it!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an outer For, use Do Until

```
'...
shift_line = 3

With month_lines
    Do
        If .Cells(shift_line, 1).Value <> "" Then
            For shifts = shift_line To .Cells(shift_line, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + shift_line
                .Cells(shift_line + .Cells(shifts, 9).Value, 12 + .Cells(shifts, 8).Value) = .Cells(shifts, 7).Value
            Next shifts
        End If
        shift_line = .Cells(shift_line, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Loop Until shift_line > last_row
End With
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you.